# Create a new separate window for Main Program

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

So, I am trying to create a splash screen for my app; the splash screen is a QMainWindow  and the main program is also QMainWindow. The problem is that when I hide the splash screen and show the main program, it doesn't have its own separate window that can be minimized and dealt with like rest of Windows programs. how can I achieve this?

here is the code for my splash screen

*Updated: changed the splash screen from QMainWindow to QWidget

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import os
import sys

class ThreadProgress(QThread):
    mysignal = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
    def run(self):
        # here I list all my imports
        self.mysignal.emit(100)
        
class Splash(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Splash, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        pixmap = QPixmap("photos/splash.png")
        self.splash_image = QLabel(self)
        self.splash_image.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(350, 300))
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.splash_image)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        progress = ThreadProgress(self)
        progress.mysignal.connect(self.progress)
        progress.start()
        
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def progress(self, finished):
        self.pbar.setValue(finished)
        if finished == 100:
            self.hide()
            self.start_main()
    
    def start_main(self):
        from MainWindow import MainWindow
        main = MainWindow(self)
        main.show()

def main():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Splash()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

main()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a QMainWindow as a splash screen, instead of using [QSplashScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html)? Also, you're already using `super(Splash, self).__init__(parent)`, calling `QMainWindow.__init__(self)` afterwards is pointless. That said, it doesn't have a separate window because you're creating `MainWindow` with `self` as argument, which will make the new `MainWindow` instance as a *child widget* of the current. You could create the instance without a parent and set a reference for it (`self.main = ...`) but my that would be meaningless: first of all ->

Comment: -> as said, you should use QSplashScreen, then you certainly should *not* use the splash widget (whatever class you decide to use) as your first and main object in your program. It should probably be a standalone widget that is created when the application starts, possibly at the beginning of the `__init__` of the *actual* main window (or even the QApplication)

Comment: I didn't use QSplashScreen because there was no useful documentation for it in Python. However, using `self.main = ....` instead of `MainWindow(self)` just solved my problem, if you please post it as an answer, I will check it as correct. Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest to avoid using another class for a splash screen, especially QMainWindow. I know that sometimes the documentation might be poor or scarse for PyQt users, but that shouldn't lead you to use the wrong classes: QMainWindow is *not* intended for that (you should at least use QWidget), and has features that can potentially become bugs. Sorry, but I won't post an answer for something that I believe being wrong, misleading or even harmful, and there are plenty of answers about creating a new window that are too similar to yours, and a new answer wouldn't add anything useful.

Comment: Instead, I'd suggest you to carefully read its documentation (linked above; as all Qt official docs, they're C++ oriented, but their functions are the same for Qt in 99% of cases, and you can also look for the [PySide oriented docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtWidgets/QSplashScreen.html)) and do some research even here on StackOverflow (or a simple "site:stackoverflow.com pyqt qsplashscreen" on google, if you want), as there's plenty of related questions that can give you a lot of hints on its usage.

Comment: I took your advice concerning using QWidget instead of using QMainWindow. The problem with using QSplashScreen is that I want to show a progress bar beneath the image, which I assume from what I read would require a lot of work with QSplashScreen. Instead, I did it with QWidget easily.